# How in Interface Builder can you select a rectangular group of items when they're on top of a background item?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, interface-builder

I've had this problem several times now, and never found a satisfactory solution:   If I want to move a group of items with a view all together in Interface Builder, and these items are all on top of a larger background item, I can't put a selection rectangle around the items in the view because any click and drag in the view initiates a move of the background item.   In other words, every pixel in the area I'm interested in (and nearby) has a "hand" mouse pointer, no "arrow" pointer is available so I can't drag out a rectangle selection box.

cmd-clicking individual items  to build up the group only works when they are separate, and only when there are a few of them.  Sometimes I want to select a "pile" of items all on top of each other.

Is there some way to "select for moving" by clicking in the .xib item list?   Double clicking a single item selects it for moving in the view, but I have't found a way to add to the "select for moving" selection this way.

So far the best way I've found is temporarily moving the background out of the way and then putting it back but this is unsatisfactory, and wouldn't work with a more complex background arrangement.

How have others done this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know what you mean, and I have found a slightly better solution: go to the list view and...

1. drag either the background view or your custom view up to the root hierarchy level (adjacent to File's Owner)
2. double click on your custom view and edit away using drag-box-selection
3. when finished, drag the view back into its original hierarchy position

The key here is that the GUI editor only edits one root object at a time, so moving the background vs. 'foreground' views into separate root objects allows you to edit them separately.  Woo!

Comment: Step 2 is all you need to do. Just drill down into the parent view of the views you want to move before you select them.

Comment: Peter -- good point, that does work if the background view and the custom view are side by side, but there are cases when I've wanted a complex view that contains its own background view, in which case you'll have these problems selecting.  It's totally valid to make a new view, put everything in there, then do just step #2, but it seems weird to reparent things because of a selection quirk.  But maybe it's worth it.

Comment: Thanks.  It appears then that the only way is a variant of "move the background away" -- via reparent, or some other technique of separating the background from the elements on top of it.

Answer (score 3):

This is my solution to this problem: Select the background images/object that you don't want to move and set its width to 1 and then, after a comfortable layout editing, restore its original width. This works for me.

Answer (score 3):

Use the left hand side list view and multi-select a range by clicking on the first item in the range then shift-click on the last item.  Use ctrl-click to unselect some items if necessary.  As items are selected they will also show as being selected in the interface view on the right.

Once have set up all the selected items, cmd-click on the selected items in the right hand side interface view and drag.

Comment: The question is specifically about selecting the items in the preview, not the items list.

Comment: Your question asked - Is there some way to "select for moving" by clicking in the .xib item list?  The answer is to select them using combination of click-shift or ctrl-click, then once selected in the left hand side list you can then CTRL-click on any of the selected items in the right hand Side preview pane and it will move all of the selected items at once in the preview pane.

Answer (score 0):

In the list of objects, cmd+click each one you want to select them all. In the interface hold command and click and drag the stack of items. Drag them to where you want them and release cmd. If you don't release the button they will rubber band back to their original position.